# Как программно анимировать ImageView

Tags: java, android

Уже третий день бьюсь - не хватает мозгов/знаний
Пытаюсь заставить imageView перемещаться по экрану (Animation не подходит ImageView должен быть кликабельным во время движения)
 Дальше кривой код который я написал ImageView перемещается но после 7 секундной паузы сразу в конечную точку. Помогите разобраться как сделать чтобы ImageView перемещался в каждом цикле (Визуально перемещался).

```
     package bpk.light.app_1_0;

     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.FrameLayout;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
     import android.widget.Toast;

    /**
    * Created by Admin on 14.04.2017.
    */

    public class FourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView img1;
    //int max = 10;
    //int min = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x;
    Thread t;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_four);
        //int x = (int)( Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
        int x = 0;
        Intent intent4 = getIntent();
        String imgname = intent4.getStringExtra("imgname");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(FourActivity.this, imgname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        switch (imgname) {
            case "A=1":
                img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anim1);
                break;
            case "A=2":
                img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anim2);
                break;
            case "A=3":
                img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anim3);
                break;
        }
        while (i <7) {
            t = Thread.currentThread();
            img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            t = Thread.currentThread();
            layoutParams.setMargins(x, x * 2, 0, 0);
            img1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            x = x + 10;
            i++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как это так, `switch/case` со строкой?

Comment: @Flippy в Java 7 аргумент в виде строки поддерживается в блоке switch - case, а android позволяет использовать Java 7 с некоторых пор.

Comment: Чтобы View был кликабельным при перемещении, нужно использовать анимацию свойств - [Property Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `ViewPropertyAnimator`

```
imageView.animate()
    .translationX(0)
    .translationY(0)
    .setDuration(500)
    .start();
```

Следовательно весь цикл нужно снести, вы занимаетесь **не тем**. Кол выше переместит `View` в верхний левый угол экрана, так как там начало координат. Чтобы сдвинуть `View` вправо на 10 пикселей нужно выставить `.translationX(10)`, если влево то -10. Если вверх/вниз то аналогично с Y. Дерзайте!

Так же вы можете менять в цикле координаты через `setX` и `setY`.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал через imageView.animate() всё работает!

Comment: @Light, если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его верным (галочка слева)